# What can IBM Rational Rose do Microsoft Visio can't?

Tags: oop, visio, uml, rational-rose

I looked for rational rose feature list but what they present is more of a verbose instead of a list of features. Do any of these support creation of class templates from UML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, Visio is a drawing tool while Rational rose is a modeling tool. To me, these are [two different families of tools](http://modeling-languages.com/drawing-tools-vs-modeling-tools/). Of course, it´s difficult to classify some tools in clearly one of the two categories but in general I´d say that the main difference is that drawing tools do not understand the model you are drawing, they just let you represent it. This implies that most likely they will not be able to check if the model is correct or to generate code from it.

Comment: valid point. from experience, I know visio allows illogical combinations where rose doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

As Jordi mentions - the difference is that tools like Rose (and others) understand the rules of UML.  They allow you to catch modelling errors, and more importantly, allow you to refactor models more easily.  Say your "Customer" class has been renamed "Account" - change it in the model and all references to Customer will be updated.

Remember -a good UML model is a bit like a circuit diagram - it has rules that allow you be very precise about what you want to convey. There are approaches to modelling that mean you generate the application rather than code it directly (or code very little of it).  Many embedded/safety critical systems are built this way.

What are you trying to achieve with your UML diagrams?  This might help people answer your question more precisely.

Also - if you have a requirement to use UML 2.x - I would recommend Rational Software Architect or(depending on your modelling needs) System Architect as Rose is more geared to UML 1.x.

Answer (score 1):

Well,

Creating of class templates is not big issue...Many cheap UML tools do it...And many of them allow you to write your own transformation such as

```
Sparx Systems Enterprise Architect  tool
[www.sparxsystems.com][1]
```

But i never seen a practical benefit from those mechanical conversion...

> But Visio is generally bad choice for me...

**It is not easy to structure your models**...It is just drawing tool...**Try some cheap UML tools such as Sparx Systems Enterprise Architect.**.. They are better...even better than IBM tools in many situations...
And

- Those tools can able to generate class diagram from source code which
  Viso can not...
- Depending on your programming language some of them    also able to
  generate sequence diagrams from code execution...

But do not forget The best UML modeling tool is **whiteboard...**
You can make your walls agile modeling enviroments with some cheap products:

**Whiteboard-Like Sheets For Agile Modeling On Walls**

- http://www.magicwhiteboard.net/ [ tr]
- http://www.magicwhiteboard.co.uk/ [ uk]

Answer (score 0):

Rational was the best UML tool in the world but since its eclipse integration and the use of the GMF framework it is now so unstable, so slow, no direct control of the model etc... than even a drawing tool like Visio is better !!